# Methods used to verify a "cancel" button in web application works

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, assert

I am working on test cases for a web application. The current job requires me to confirm that when you press the logout button, the prompt comes up, you can click the cancel button on the prompt, and the prompt will close.

I am wondering about verify and assertion methods I could use to confirm this functionality works. The cancel button does nothing else but close the pop up prompt. What would you guys use?

Here's some code:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/img"));
actions.moveToElement(logout).build().perform();
WebElement logoutHover = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/img"));
logoutHover.click();
WebElement logoutPushed = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flow']/div[1]/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/img"));
logoutPushed.click();
WebElement cancel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[5]/div"));
actions.moveToElement(cancel).build().perform();
WebElement cancel2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[5]/div"));
cancel2.click();

WebElement pageText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div"));
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", pageText.contains("PRODUCT LIST"));
```

This assert method does not work. My initial idea was that if you hit the cancel button, I can assert that the user is still on the same page (my code for this does not work). Would it be a smarter choice to assert that the prompt is not present anymore? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It's not the correct way to do it, but maybe I could run the logout actions again? If they could not be run (do to something being wrong after the user cancels the logout) than it would fail -- but I know that is not good practice. I have searched stackoverflow for methods used to verify page elements but can not find what I need.

Comment: Those are some beastly XPaths... I would look for a simpler way to find those elements. Don't suppose you could share the relevant HTML or a link to the page?

Comment: Are you using `Actions` for some particular reason? Is there some reason that a simple `driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).click()` won't work?

Comment: @JeffC Actions was the solution to another issue I had. The web application I am working on is really finicky and is proving to be one hell of a task to deal with. It loads to our end users as an SWF file, but we have a JavaScript version for the purposes of testing. The XPaths kill me. Our developers didn't put any classes, IDs, etc, into the code. Alas, sadly I can't share the web page, but I believe your answer is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct way to do it would be to confirm that the logout prompt is no longer up and that you are still logged in. I don't know what your site looks like but for the logout prompt, find an element unique to that popup (maybe the OK or cancel button, hopefully something with an ID). Detect that it's no longer visible and then confirm you are still logged in by some means... look for a user name or ???

```
// click the logout button

// click the cancel button

List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.id("sampleId")); // a button on the confirm popup
if (button.isEmpty())
{
    // the logout confirmation popup is not visible

    // verify that you are still logged in... maybe look for a user name or ???
}
else
{
    // log a failure here because you couldn't cancel the logout popup
}
```